# VS2010: run command when solution configuration changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, scripting, automation

We're writing Python modules in C++ using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. We output Debug and Release modules in a different directory, and a configuration file for the Python part of our code determines which version is loaded.

During development in C++ I often switch between Release and Debug configurations. Sometimes I forget to update the Python config file, and then I build in Debug but the Release version is still being loaded.

What I would like is to automatically update the configuration file, so that when I switch the VS2010 Solution configuration from Release to Debug (and the other way around), the Python configuration file is automatically updated accordingly.

**Update**: the solution consists of roughly two dozen projects, and there is no single project that will *always* be built. I could use a pre-buld command, but I would have to add it to each and every project, which I'm trying to avoid.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Kind regards,
Sybren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has pre- and post-build events. Those give access macro's that also give you the build mode (ConfigurationName).
You could update the Python config file in the pre-build command.

Things like

`if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug`

are possible.

In some projects I used this in combination with batch/cmd files that take the $(ConfigurationName) as a parameter.

Comment: The reply was placed before the update. As i don't think there's a way to trigger something when you change from Debug to Release (or other way around), i would add a dummy project that always gets build (you could configure a dependency to that project). That project would do the post/pre-build command.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. How do I tell VS2010 that a project should always be built?

Comment: The solution: a custom build step setup like this: Outputs: non-existing; Execute After: PreBuildEvent